# Get the date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, select

I know that `SELECT Now()` returns the current DateTime, but how can I just return the date, so instead of this:

```
Month.Day.Year.Hour.Minute.Second
```

I can just do:

```
Month.Day.Year
```

So what must I do to get the M.D.Y instead of M.D.Y.H.M.S in mysql?

Also, how can I get the `H.M.S` part as well?

Comment: Dont know about mysql but you can try ``cast(now() as date)`` however this will still give you the formatting of your desired collation. if you want to hardcode the datelayout you should use some equivalence of t-sql datepart()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT CURDATE(); //is what you need
```

Please check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) for more information.

To format date in month/Day/Year, [check this.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y');
```

If you want a dot(.) to separate the date like `Month.Day.Year`, you can do this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m.%d.%Y');
```

To get the H.M.S part, you can do the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Now(), '%H.%i.%S');
```